# Don't know how to build task 'active_storage:install' (--no-skip-active-storage)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using Rails 7.0.4.3, and I have a really hard time trying to understand why the following is working successfully ...

```
$ rails new testapp
$ cd testapp
$ bin/rails active_storage:install
Copied migration 20230522144343_create_active_storage_tables.active_storage.rb from active_storage
```

... but NOT the following?

```
$ rails new testapp --minimal --no-skip-active-storage
$ cd testapp
$ bin/rails active_storage:install
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'active_storage:install' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)
```

Did I miss something with the `--no-skip-active-storage` option?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to config/application.rb

Now uncomment #require "active_storage/engine

Then, run again:

$ bin/rails active_storage:install

Answer (score 0):

I tried the --no-skip-active-storage and it makes no difference, Additianally,In the latest versions of Rails (6.0 and above), Active Storage comes preinstalled and ready to use out of the box.

To enable Active Storage functionality, simply uncomment the line require "active_storage/engine" in the config/application.rb file. This line is already present and commented out by default.

-skip-active-storage workes, it skips all the files and configratoins for active_storage, but cannot find the --no-skip-active-storage option in documentation. By default the --no-skip-active-storage is enabled, so it will have no effect, enen if you add it.